# While Loop not Breaking when Condition is Met

Tags: php, while-loop

I've got several working while loops in my function but this one I just can't get to work as it's supposed to. I assumed that `while($variable == false)` would break out of the loop as soon as `$variable = true;` occurs. Here's a bare bones version, with only two statements inside the loop.

```
$excluded = false;
while($excluded == false):
    $excluded = in_array(strtolower($extension), $GLOBALS['codexts']) ? true : false;
    $excluded = $file != "." && $file != ".." ? false : true; 
    break;
endwhile;
```

Inside the loop, the first definition does produce `false` when it's suppose to, but the loop doesn't break. It goes on to the second one, which returns true. If I change the second one to this:

```
$excluded = $excluded ? $excluded : ($file != "." && $file != ".." ? false : true);
```

...then I get the result I want, but only because I'm correcting for the failure of the while loop to break when `$excluded` is first defined as `true`. What am I doing wrongly here?

**UPDATE**
I just reread the manual, and apparently I missed this part:

> The value of the expression is checked each time at the beginning of the loop, so even if this value changes during the execution of the nested statement(s), execution will not stop until the end of the iteration

That's why the iterations were reverting back to false. I do need to do manual conditional breaks after all.

Comment: Are you sure it goes on to the second loop? Your `break;` statement does not have a condition surrounding it, it will be executed whether or not your `$excluded` is true or false.

Comment: Missing curly brackets .....

Comment: The break statement is at the end of the loop, to cover those iterations that never return true, so the loop doesn't get stuck. But I assure you, there are iterations that are returning true on the first statement, but not behaving like they're true, hence that's how I know it's going on to the second statement. The break at the end is not the issue.

Comment: No, missing curly brackets is not the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
$excluded = false;
while($excluded == false) {
   $excluded = in_array(strtolower($extension), $GLOBALS['codexts']) ? true : false;
   if ($excluded == true) {
     break;
   }
    $excluded = $file != "." && $file != ".." ? false : true; 
    break;
} 
?>
```

Comment: It took me a minute to see what the difference was. Curly brackets. Well, I tried it. Still not working. Thanks though.

Comment: @Thom:do you need the while loop to break if first statement is true ??

Comment: Yes. That's what while loops are suppose to do. Break when the condition is changed.

Comment: I shouldn't have to use break. While loops are supposed to break when the condition is changed. That's what they do.

Comment: @Thom That's right, you wouldn't need to have a `break;` in your case. One key point is, nothing in your loop is changing, so depending on your values it maybe executed once or infinite.

Comment: I take that back, Sajad. You're right. Apparently I misunderstood how the while loop works. If you want to edit your answer to include a break, I'll accept it. Apparently, the while loop continues to the end even if the condition is changed.

Comment: Cheezburger: $excluded is changing. From false to true. I'm not sure how you can say that. Regardless, I just reread the manual and I need to do a manual break. That's my answer.

Comment: @Thom:is it ok now ? i have added the if statement

Comment: Yup. Thanks for forcing me back to the manual. My $notion was false.

Comment: Nuts you need a break statement. Silly PHP

Answer (score 0):

Q: Why don't use use conventional syntax?

Q: Why a redundant "break"?

Q: Why are you setting the expression twice before testing, and do you really need "?:" here?  Twice???

Q: Can't you simplify the expression that changes your flag (changes "$excluded")?

SUGGESTION:

```
$myvar = false;
while(!$myvar) {
  $myvar = << something that sets/clears my flag >>
}
```

Comment: Q: Which part of my syntax is unconventional?
A: The break statement is at the end of the loop, to cover those iterations that never return true, so the loop doesn't get stuck. It's standard protocol. It is NOT redundant. 
Q: I don't understand your third question: "setting the expression twice before testing."

Comment: It doesn't get much simpler than `if in_array() true/false`.

Comment: And your suggestion is exactly what I'm doing already. `!$myvar` is the same as `$myvar == false`, and I tried `!$excluded` many times before posting here.

Comment: use the wrapped value of $myvar for your while `while !$myvar.wrappedValue {`